# Чтение epub файлов в C#

Tags: c#, epub

Хочу сделать читалку на C#, подскажите как правильно открывать и считывать epub файлы, какие классы, библиотеки есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать [библиотеку ePubReader](http://epubreader.codeplex.com/).
Есть еще [библиотека EPUB Sharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/epubsharp/), была в бета-стадии.

**Источник:** [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870594/is-there-a-c-sharp-epub-library).

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.